# Арифметические операции без фукнции

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал практические работы с использованием функций. Препод говорит сделать без функций. У меня уже голова не варит. Поможете? Мои примеры:
1) Сложить числа и в зависимости от суммы(больше 36, меньше 36) вывести сообщение.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.2</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
 <script>
 function Suma(){
 var a=prompt("Введите первое число",'');
 var b=prompt("Введите второе число",'');
 var c=prompt("Введите третье число",'');
 var s=+a + +b + +c;
 if (s<36) alert('По данной дисциплине у вас задолженность');
 else if (s>=36) alert('У вас скоро экзамен');}
 </script>
</head> 
<body>
 <script>
 Suma();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Второе: Открыть всплывающее окно с текстом по нажатии на кнопку

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.3</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
 <script>
 function Writ(){
 alert('«Java Script. Дисциплина Web - программирование»');}
 </script>
</head> 
<body> 
 
 <center><button onclick="Writ();">Открыть всплывающее окно</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Ну и то, что меня пугает: сложить числа кратные 5, вычислить произведение положительных чисел. Ввод закончится при наборе цифры 0. Введенные числа вывести в виде нумерованного списка. А результаты в таблицу.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.4</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
 <script>
 function suma(){
 for (i=0; x !== 0; i++){
   x = parseInt(prompt("введите число:",''));
   numbers[i] = x;
   if (( x % 5 === 0) && (x === 5)) {sum += x;}
   if (x > 0) {pro *= x;}
 } 
 
}
 function Vivod(){
 var size;
 document.open();
 document.write("<ol>");
 for(size = 0; size < i-1; size ++){
 document.write("<li>"); 
 document.write(numbers[size]);
 document.write("</li>"); 
 }
 document.write("</ol>");
 document.close();
}
 </script>
</head> 
<body> 
 <script>
 var sum=0;
 var pro=1;
 var x=1;
 var i;
 var numbers = [];
 suma();
 </script>
 <table height=200 width=300 border="solid" cellspacing=1>
 <tr>
 <td>Сумма чисел, кратных 5: <script>document.write(sum)</script></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Произведение положительных чисел: <script>document.write(pro)</script></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
 Vivod();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать функции ради того, чтобы их написать. Так делать не нужно. Функции пишутся, чтобы исключить избыточность в коде (2 абсолютно одинаковых и объёмных куска кода лучше написать один раз в функции, а потом её вызвать, где это будет нужно). Соответственно, уберите лишние функции у себя, потому что они не повторяют код и используются только 1 раз (и Вы явно не будете их использовать где-то ещё).

1. Уберите просто функцию и оставьте тело функции. Всё будет работать и так.
2. `<center><button onclick="alert('«Java Script. Дисциплина Web - программирование»');">Открыть всплывающее окно</button></center>` - тоже бесполезная функция была, можно писать и напрямую в ивентах небольшие части кода (но не всегда полезно).
3. Тоже самое, что и в первом случае.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.4</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
</head> 
<body> 
 <script>
 var sum=0;
 var pro=1;
 var x=1;
 var i, size;
 var numbers = [];
 for (i=0; x !== 0; i++){
   x = parseInt(prompt("введите число:",''));
   numbers[i] = x;
   if (( x % 5 === 0) && (x === 5)) {sum += x;}
   if (x > 0) {pro *= x;}
 }
 document.open();
 document.write("<ol>");
 for(size = 0; size < i-1; size ++){
 document.write("<li>"); 
 document.write(numbers[size]);
 document.write("</li>"); 
 }
 document.write("</ol>");
 document.close();
 </script>
 <table height=200 width=300 border="solid" cellspacing=1>
 <tr>
 <td>Сумма чисел, кратных 5: <script>document.write(sum)</script></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Произведение положительных чисел: <script>document.write(pro)</script></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спорное утверждение, функции используются не только для повторяющегося кода, но и для выделения отдельных логических частей в "подпрограмму". Код с функциями намного легче читать, правильно названная ф-ция сразу говорит о том, что эта часть кода делает и часто бывает, что читающему код не важно как она это делает. И, честно говоря, не понятно, чем тут преподу помешали ф-ции

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич желание препода - закон ) у нас тип был по алгоритмам, так он заставлял рисовать в тетрадках результаты выполнения программ (окно cmd с результатами)...и рисовали ж

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич Да, может и в таком виде использоваться, но это уже ближе к принципам ООП. Но тут выделять код в функции бессмысленно, если вся программа состоит из одной этой функции.

Answer (score 0):

Так без функций, и последнее я поправил вам (стилизацию сами доделаете)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.2</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
</head> 
<body>
 <script>
    var a=prompt("Введите первое число",'');
    var b=prompt("Введите второе число",'');
    var c=prompt("Введите третье число",'');
    var s=+a + +b + +c;
    if (s<36) alert('По данной дисциплине у вас задолженность');
    else if (s>=36) alert('У вас скоро экзамен');
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.3</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
</head> 
<body> 
  <center><button onclick="alert('«Java Script. Дисциплина Web - программирование»');">Открыть всплывающее окно</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Практическая работа 5.4</title>
 <meta charset= "UTF-8">
 <script>
 
  var sum = 0;
  var pro = 1;
  var mass = [];
  document.open();
  while(true)
  {
    x = parseInt(prompt("введите число:",''));
    if (x === 0) break;
    mass.push(x);
    
  }
  mass.forEach(e => {
    document.write(e+"\n");
    
    if (e%5 === 0) sum += e;
    if (e>0) pro *= e;
  });
  
  document.write("\n\n\nСумма чисел, кратных 5: " + sum);
  document.write("Произведение положительных чисел: " + pro);
  document.close();
 

 </script>
</head> 
<body> 
 
 
</body>
</html>
```